# Delete Quickbooks Journal Entries QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Is there a way to programatically delete Journal Entries in Quickbooks desktop (Enterprise Ed 2013) using an API like QBXML? I understand that the usual practice would be a compensating entry, but this use case calls for deleting the JE. I see that `JournalEntryModRq` allows you to modify it, but not delete it. It can be deleted using the UI, so it must be possible, yes?

We are using the QB Web Connector, any other options if not via QBXML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TxnDel` to delete an transaction-type object using qbXML.

Here's some example (from [this QuickBooks wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks), specifically [this page](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Deleting_%22Transaction%22_Objects_%28Invoices,_Journal_Entries,_etc.%29)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TxnDelRq>
      <TxnDelType>JournalEntry</TxnDelType>
      <TxnID>ABCD-1234</TxnID>
    </TxnDelRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```